# Client Socket as the listener?

Tags: java, sockets, groovy, server, client

I need all my clients attached to a server to be socket listeners. The server will attempt to connect to a specific client and instruct it to preform a various task via a socket message. So my question is, can my Java Client be the ServerSocket and listen for Server requests? And is it possible for a webpage loaded on a client machine to know the clients IP address to send the message too. We have an application running on our server that has many clients attached and when a button is pressed on the clients webpage it will attempt to connect with this client and send a message to it. Most of the time servers are listeners, but in our case we need just opposite where the client is listener waiting for server requests. But the server needs to know what the client IP address is to establish the connection since our clients are attached via DHCP.

Btw, 
All our clients are basically running a webpage from our server and each client has it own PC. The thing I need to do is control a USB device on each client machine. I have control over the website software, so my goal was to use sockets to do this since controlling a clients external hardware is very difficult remotely. So what I was going to do is write a Java app and that runs on the client machine acting as a listener which when someone presses a button on the webpage the server will attempt to connect to the client machine and send the message down to it. I’m just not sure how to handle this from the server side, so it knows what client it’s talking too since I don’t want to broadcast the message to all clients, but only the one the button was pressed on, keep in mind each client is attached via DHCP addressing, so I can't hardcode the hostID. I can attach java/groovy or ajax scripts to the button event on the server side, but I’m not sure how to setup the socket protocol on the server to make this work.

Here is an example of a socket connection I could use on the client / server side, but I need to know the clients DHCP IP address is to make it work properly.

**Server side requesting client task**

```
public void requestSocket() 
{ 
 Socket socket = null;
 private BufferedReader in = null;
 private PrintWriter out = null;

//Create socket connection for server
    String serverAddress = "localhost"; // Needs to be the client DHCP IP address.
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 4444);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unknown host: " + serverAddress);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch  (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("No I/O");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

**Client side listener acting as the server**

```
public void listenSocket()
{ 
    int portNumber = 4444;
    ServerSocket server = null;
    Socket client = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try
    {
          client = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port " + portNumber);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    try
    {
          server = client.accept();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Accept failed :" + portNumber);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    try
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Read failed");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            line = in.readLine();
            //Send data back to client
            out.println(line);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Read failed");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
 }
```

Can anyone help answer these questions?

Comment: First: what are your clients? Java Client or Webpage in browser?

Answer (score 1):

First: what are your clients? Java Client or Webpage in browser?

Second: if it is JavaClient it can be only ServerSocket in it to listen what your server will tell and Server must know IP and port of each clients to do that.

Third: for Java Client actually JMS with Topic is there for such tasks. Server publishes message, while clients listen and do with message what is needed.

and Forth:
If it is a webpage there is only one way - from JavaScript (or auto-refresh mechanism) browser can ask Server periodically (by timer) for new messages. With HTML there is no way for the server to initiate any actions on client browser.
It is always request-response.

Updated:
try something like that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Loop Back</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:4444" id=in_form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>IN_MSG:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="IN_MSG" id="IN_MSG"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" formmethod="post">Post Something</button>
   </form>  
  </body>
</html>
```

and see what you get in your background Java listening on port 4444. Mayb it can be enough? you can pass anything you may need as separate input fields and them can be hidden as well as whole form can be invisible...

If you need some data from server prepared for background java think the way on picture to avoid communication from server to background java. 
[image]

main point is to avoid direct communication from server to background java. All passes through the browser, so no pain with IP, ports, proxy, security etc. Browser and javascript on webpage take care of all...

Comment: I edited the example above to explain further. The client machines are just PC attached to a webserver. The server is the initiator in our case and the client needs to be listening for the request to perform the task. This should be possible, since I'm sure that others have done this before. Maybe an applet is a better approach for this, but I have no idea how to implement it that way. The socket method should work, I hope!

Comment: Also, there will be a Java app running on each client machine in the background to handle the server requests when a button is pressed on the webpage.

Comment: OK. As I can say you are almost there. but your client = server.accept(); must be in the indefinite loop and after you got client socket you need to start another thread to work with it and so on. As of now that code takes only one message from server and gone. BTW Applet is not a good idea since you will have to do more with security manager to open sockets and code will be the same.

Comment: BTW from communication prospective your clients are not Clients but Servers, while your server is a Client :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code above is just illustrating what we want to do, but thanks for pointing a few things out.

So, how is it possible for the server side to know the client's IP address that has the webpage loaded to send the message too. How do I set this up on the server side with this code?  socket = new Socket("Client DHCP IP", 4444); How do I derive "Client DHCP IP"?

Comment: Somehow when request to that page comes to the server it must be registered somewhere in the server (e.g. activeClientsList in memory, cache or such) which in turn be available for your server - that one which will send messages later. In that case you will have actual client IP (of course if they are not behind Proxy, firewall etc.)

Comment: To get it from where? there is only one point when you can get client IP - when you got request to the web page. Or you have to have a registering (or advertise/announcement) mechanism when your background java starts on client machine. Of course in opposite direction - from your client to the server. Still server must have a list of clients to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your info. It seems like this should be a trivial thing to do, to have a client listening for messages from a server that's triggered from an event on a client webpage. I can't imagine this being the first time anyone has ever done this =) I'll just keep searching the web unless someone else can provide some information how the server can connect to a client listener and send it a task.

Comment: That's right, it is a trivial task it-self.  Like:  user clicks the button - it goes to the server as request, then you have user's IP at this point on server. Server can push the message back to that IP on your port 4444 and if that background java running it takes it and does what it must do. Code to that must be in server jsp/servlet or whatever accepts that request.. But if server needs to initiate any actions on client by it-self, it is another story. Sorry, that is what I though yesterday evening...

Comment: Webpage to client hardware control is a pain to pull off, there are so many ways to do it, it's finding the best way that's hard =) Would it be possible to use an Ajax script running on the webpage to make just a localhost/port call back to the client listener and send a socket message this way or just send a command that I can parse off the end of the address and have my client app receive it? The AJAX call from the webpage could just use the localhost address without knowing the actual client IP, is that right? Could you let me?

Comment: Sure it is possible from web page to the localhost:4444. And not even Ajax is needed. As example it can be non-visible form and by click button it can Submit HTTP Request to the localhost:4444. BTW for the sockets it is not necessary be exact IP address, it can be host name, then DNS will be involved.

Comment: So would something as simple as using socket = new Socket(“localhost”, 4444); work in a script attached to a button event on the page. On my website forms I can attach java/groovy or even ajax scripts to the button event. When the page is loaded on the client will that localhost address point to the client its loaded on and connect that way with client listener? Gosh, that would be simple if that is case then I don’t need to worry about the client IP address on the webpage button event code.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with java/groovy embeded into web page and how browser will handle it with security. But definitely localhost is alias for 127.0.0.1 IP which is IP loop-back and it goes back to the local machine. There must be just a ServerSocket which listens on that port (4444). What I meant before: even if you have simple html <form action="http://localhost:4444"> then by submitting it from simple submit button will send a request to http://localhost:4444

Comment: maybe you do not need to make things more complex with embedded Java, Groovy, Ajax etc. ? try what is in updated answer...

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for helping me understand all this. I tried your example tonight. With the client socket server running, If I type in Test in the message box the Client server responds back with the following message, but without the "test" string and browser stays locked  on to the client until I close the client connection then it reports a HTML error. Is there a way to use sockets in the HTML form to get data back from client? I'll need this at some point when I hook up a card reader to our system to read a card Id into the webpage? Will the form approach work for this?

Comment: Here is the webpage form information sent back to the client socket.
Client ACK: POST / HTTP/1.1
Client ACK: Host: localhost:4444
Client ACK: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Client ACK: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Client ACK: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Client ACK: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Client ACK: DNT: 1
Client ACK: Connection: keep-alive
Client ACK: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Client ACK: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Client ACK: Content-Length: 11

Comment: You do not need sockets in HTML and there is no way to use such things.  As long as HTTP is used then you have to follow http protocol. Browser expects it. After you read from socket, you have to write response back. Then what you post as page, is not complete. Only headers are there. what you typed is in body after that like IN_MSG=what you typed. If you change form nethod to GET first line will be like GET /?IN_MSG=what you typed HTTP/1.1

Comment: But that example was just an idea how it can be done. And with Ajax all can be easier. Good luck. PS. HTTP is not complex protocol :)

Comment: I do not work with Ajax for a long time. But example from any kind of tutorial, quick start etc. will be good